# Cannot see files in Time Machine folders

Tags: backup, time-machine

I've been using an external Harddrive for Time Machine backups. Yesterday I made a Time Machine backup before resetting my MacBook Pro to factory settings. I've now connected the Time Machine Hard Drive to my other MacBook and can see the folders but they have a red mark next to them as shown and when I enter them they are empty. I checked the Get Info as shown below but not sure why is that? Any advice please?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's probably an account number mis-match. The Mac doesn't know who 'you' are, only the account number - 501 for the first admin, 502, 503 for subsequent. If you move to a Mac where the numbering is different, this is what happens, plus TM has 'special' permissions unlike regular folders. What exactly are you trying to do anyway? Time Machine isn't really designed to be accessed at a file level, only though the TM GUI interface.